# Slide all selected edges?

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

I want to delete part of an object like in the picture below. But since I will transfer it to another 3D application, I must not change the number of vertex or face.

I can slide the selected edges to the next edge one by one with "Edit Mode" and "Edge Slide" and make the part I want to delete invisible, but this process is very troublesome. How can I make this process easier?

the selected edges are the parts I want to delete
[image: the selected edges are the parts I want to delete]

the part I made invisible by shifting the selected edges to the left without deleting any edge or vertex
[image: the part I made invisible by shifting the selected edges to the left without deleting any edge or vertex]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean "they're still not deleted" but at the same time you want to have the same vertex count? Deleting a mesh removes it completely, you could try subdividing or adding loop cuts to fix the topology again.

Answer (score 1):

Select the section you want deleted, make sure that one vertex on the edge you want remaining is the active one.

[image]

Then set your pivot point to *Active Element*.

[image]

Then scale it to 0 on whatever applicable axis (X in this case.)

[image]

Comment: That's the logical answer, but not what the OP is asking. The OP is asking to delete the vertices in Blender without changing the vertex count. Impossible to answer ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This method works for 2D objects, but has problems with 3D objects like cylinders. https://imgur.com/a/y9TZ0qq

Comment: @bumlicerto you have to do it on a specific axis, for example if it's facing upwards you can scale it on S > Z > 0